# Check if any element in List begins with a specific character

Tags: prolog

I've a list of words, for example [cola,fanta,pepsi] and I want to write a predicate that checks if any of the elements begins with the character specified.

My code so far is as follows:

```
chk_first_letter(Char,[]):-fail.
chk_first_letter(Char, [H|T]):-
    perform_check(Char, H);
    chk_first_letter(Char, T).
perform_check(Char,[First|_]):-memberchk(Char, First).
```

However consulting my file and calling chk_first_letter(p,[cola,fanta,pepsi]) gives me no even if pepsi begins with a p.

I've tried with Char==First instead of memberchk(Char,First) but it didn't work either. I'm not sure about the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First attempt:

```
chk_first_letter(Char, Atoms) :- member(A, Atoms), atom_chars(A, [Char|_]).
```

[atom_chars](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_chars/2)/2 it's an ISO predicate.

Your code it's almost working, can be simplified this way:

```
chk_first_letter(Char, [H|T]):-
    atom_chars(H, [Char|_]);
    chk_first_letter(Char, T).
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to replace the call to atom_chars/2 by a call to sub_atom/5 (as Boris suggested). No need to convert an atom to a list just to look into its first character.

Answer (score 4):

You have a list of atoms, and your `perform_check/2` compares two atoms. An atom is *not* a list of characters! You need to use atom processing, for example:

```
perform_check(First, Word) :-
    sub_atom(Word, 0, 1, _After, First).
```

http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/manual/html_node/gprolog043.html#sec200

There are a bunch of other built-ins in this section that could be used, for example for breaking the atom into characters or character codes (`atom_chars/2` and `atom_codes/2`). But what `sub_atom/5` also allows you to do easily:

prefixes of any length:

```
sub_atom(Word, 0, _Length, _After, Prefix).
```

suffixes:

```
sub_atom(Word, _Before, _Length, 0, Suffix).
```

Comment: This is the best solution w.r.t. performance that fits the problem description. It doesn't create atoms and lists that need will need to be garbage-collected.

Comment: @PauloMoura Thank you :) it is conceptually "right", and the most general one, and can easily be adjusted to compare atoms of any length or for example suffixes. PS edited for completeness

Answer (score 2):

`memberchk` expects to be called with a list as the second argument.  In your case, you're providing it with a single character.

And then you can probably do away with it altogether by taking advantage of unification:

```
perform_check(Char,[Char|_]).
```

This assumes your string type is a list of characters (whatever the character format).  If you intend to operate on atoms directly, you could do it this way instead:

```
perform_check(Char,String) :- atom_concat(Char,_,String)
```

There would be a few more steps to make your code more idiomatic, but this seems to be the actual *wrong* part of it.

Comment: I tried to consult the file with your new code, but it still gives me no. I use gprolog if it makes any sense.

Comment: Ok, I lied a bit. You also need to get your typing (strings vs lists vs symbols) straight. The quoted code currently operates on strings as lists of individual character symbols, while your invocant assumes strings as symbols. Do you need help with that as well?

Comment: There, adjusted to atoms and gprolog (I used to be moer of a SWI person).  BTW note that your first clause for `chk_first_letter` is redundant.